# Doxygen - Show a list of "using this" links?

Tags: doxygen

I'm building doxygen scripts for a code base, and have a list of datafiles.  I created fake classes (a dummy .h file) for each datafile with some descriptive text, so that references in other code will hyperlink to the page for the class.

However, I would **really** love to get the page for the datafile to show all the places it's being used.

How do I get doxygen to do this?

*Note*: the whole datafile as a fake class is just something I did to get things going in the system.  If there's some other better way, I can easily change.  I've been trying `xrefitem` and other things with no real luck.